# R - Analyse impact of categorical variables on continuous variable

Tags: r, statistics, regression, lm, categorical-data

I'm trying to analyze a data set in R where I have sales of items over time and I want to understand the impact of categorical variables on the quantity sold.

```
library("data.table")

qty <- c(100,10000,100,200,150,9000)
flavour <- c("Mint","Herb","Mint","Mint","Herb","Fruit")
category <- c("Multiple","Multiple","White","Multiple","Other","White")

sales_data <- data.frame(qty,flavour,category)

str(sales_data)

'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ qty     : num  100 10000 100 200 150 9000
 $ flavour : Factor w/ 3 levels "Fruit","Herb",..: 3 2 3 3 2 1
 $ category: Factor w/ 3 levels "Multiple","Other",..: 1 1 3 1 2 3
```

I've been looking at multipleregressions and simple linear regressions, but I feel I might be on the wrong track.  My understanding is that I can use a simple linear regression to determine a relationship between 2 continuous variables.  I can see there is a way to use multiple regressions to understand the relationship between categorical variables and continuous ones but the examples I've found seem to stop at binary values.  Does someone smoke or not for example.  Given I have multiple values for each categorical variable, is multiple regression the right way to go or have I completely gone off track?

My actual data set has around 10 categorical variables, some of which relate to location, others which relate to brands.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  And apologies if this is in the wrong place or I've missed something obvious - I'm learning stats and R at the same time so becoming confused quickly

Comment: You need to look up modelling categorical data. Most textbooks/online courses for generalised linear models will tell you about this, and its trivial to do in R (just stick your variable on the RHS of the formula).

Comment: You state 'sales of items over time', what variable in your example changes over time?

Comment: Thank you @Spacedman, I've been getting lost in what search terms to use - been down many rabbit holes.  I'll look it up, thank you.

Comment: @vincentmajor you're right, I've not included the time element - sorry, my bad.  I have a date column that represents sales for a week ending date so effectively I want to see if the influences of quantity sold change over time.  I have one column in my data set that indicates whether there was a promotion, and I also have unit price so while it may be that category usually affects quantity sold, it might be that a drop in price has a bigger impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly have a continuous dependent variable (`qty`) and a mix of  continuous and categorical predictors and they don't have to be binary.  The categorical variables should be of class `"factor"`.  For the two categorical/factor variables shown in the question:

```
fm <- lm(qty ~., sales_data)
summary(fm)
```

Comment: This assumes the data is distributed normally. You could use a glm ifyou find the data is not normally distributed or decision trees/random forests if you wanted to get really non-parametric. There's even Bayesian Belief Networks!

Comment: Some tests involve normality assumptions but if the conditions of the Gauss Markov theorem hold the regression coefficients are unbiased even in the presence of non-normality and furthermore they are best in a certain sense.

Comment: thank you @G.Grothendieck I'll look more closely at this.  One thing that has been worrying me is the subject of normal distribution.  I've read a lot of references to data needing to be normally distributed to apply a range of analyses.  It's reassuring to know that there is evidence that regressions are still applicable with non-normal data.

Comment: @user7863288 First step: figure out if your data is normal. Look up Q-Q plots if you haven't been exposed to it or just plot a quick histogram with `hist()`, if it's bell-shaped then you can move forward with lm. If it's not bell-shaped then see if it follows any distribution from the GLM family (http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/glm.html). If it does then you can just use a glm with the proper link function instead of lm.